# SPARQL serialization XQUERY

Tags: marklogic

I use sparql from XQuery with MarkLogic 9.
I serialize the results from `sem:sparql` function with `sem:query-results-serialize`, but the serialization costs a lot of time.

Is there a way to avoid it, or speed it up? By using map or something else?

my code :

```
let $_ := prof:enable(xdmp:request())
let $sparql:=concat("
SELECT ?encoche ?uriDoc1 ?uriDoc2
WHERE {
  {
      ?encoche <http://www.lefebvre-sarrut.eu/ns/hubeditorial/est-encoche-dans> ?uriDoc1 .
      ?encoche <http://www.lefebvre-sarrut.eu/ns/hubeditorial/est-defini-dans> ?uriDoc2 
  }
}
")
let $p1 := prof:report(xdmp:request())//prof:overall-elapsed
let $res:=sem:sparql($sparql, (), (), ()) 
let $p2 := prof:report(xdmp:request())//prof:overall-elapsed
let $resXML := sem:query-results-serialize($res, "xml")
let $p3 := prof:report(xdmp:request())//prof:overall-elapsed
return ($p1,$p2,$p3)
```

the return :

```
PT0.0000221S
PT0.011936S
PT0.2549374S
```

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the `sem:query-results-serialize()` method in the */Modules/MarkLogic/semantic.xqy* module, it invokes `query-results-serialize()`, which invokes the `semi:sparql-results-xml()` function from the */Modules/MarkLogic/semantics/sem-impl.xqy* module.

If you look at the `semi:sparql-results-xml()` method implementation, it is working with a map and generating the XML.

You could try importing that module and invoking that method directly, or copy the logic and profile to see if there is any area to optimize. However, at first glance I don't see any obvious areas to streamline or improve.

Comment: Thanks you for answer, I'll look at this code and see if this helps me to speed my function.